# ASP.NET Web Forms OR ASP.NET MVC framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, projects

I was looking for advice around on whether which framework to consider for my university's final year project. I'm on my final year and need to create a project management website for demonstration of my programming skills. There'll be an admin, multiple users, such as student, project supervisor and lead (clients). I've already developed few functionalities using ASP.NET Web Forms but there have been little confusion on which approach will be better, as I've seen many web solutions available online mostly with MVC framework. As it's a university project for demonstration of an online project management system, it will not be the type of large scale web development.

Answer (score 1):

It really does not matter if it will be large scale project or not, MVC is the way to do it. Web Forms are not supported anymore. Although they are great way of implementing web sites, they are old and they are really not  scaling well with today web standard requirements. My advice is to use Default MVC app template that comes with Visual Studio and adjust it to your needs. AS far as users go, you can use MVC Filters to restrict access to certain actions or functionalities.

Answer (score 0):

Use ASP.NET Core - it will be a good experience for your future interviews :)
This experience will also be useful for ASP.NET MVC 5 and WebApi 2.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same issue when i was doing my final year project. finally i decided to go with MVC and it helps me a lot to when finding an internship.it will really help in future interviews also. i just download sample MVC project from the internet and just follow their coding. i used http://www.sourcecodester.com/ to find sample MVC Projects.hope this help you.

Comment: I'm too afraid about it, as I got very limited time, the project does not throw any mandatory way of developing the program but opting with MVC may take a while now.